# Is it possible to non-destructively open the SPIKE Prime smart hub?

Tags: powered-up, spike-prime

I'm referring to this part from [SPIKE Prime](https://brickset.com/sets/45678-1):

[image: SPIKE Prime Hub]

Note that this is the same hub that will be used in [Mindstorms Inventor](https://brickset.com/sets/51515-1).

There are four Torx screws on the back side that can be accessed by removing the battery. I have removed these:

[image: Screws removed]

Even with these screws removed, the top is still tightly secured. I can force a spludger in under the ports on either side, but prying seems to only bend the top and not release it any way.

I've tried prying in the cracks at the corners, but there was no give.

Does anyone know of a way to open this part while minimizing permanent damage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, but the damage can be limited and is not externally visible.

I don't know the technical name, but each of the 4 corners are held in place with these fasteners:

[image: SPIKE Prime fastener]

Using a tool of the same diameter (2mm), they can be pressed out by applying force to the end of the fastener at the point shown below:

[image: arrow pointing to fastener]

This does damage the plastic slightly where it contacts the fastener, but if it is only done a few times the fasteners should still hold securely when reassembled.

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you know how hard this is generally to push out? I've pushed on this as hard as I can with a suitable tool, and I haven't been able to get it to budge.

Comment: Maybe need a hammer?

Comment: Indeed. I was able to dislodge these pins using a hammer and a small nail. Thanks!