# What electronics are inside the SPIKE Prime angular motors?

Tags: piece-information, electronics, disassembly, robot-inventor, spike-prime

Is there any information available about the internals of the SPIKE Prime and Robot Inventor angular motors?

What Hall-Sensor is used by the SPIKE motors?

To be more precise: I'd like to get information about the internal components of motors in a way similar to [this teardown of the SPIKE Prime Hub](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15057/what-internal-electronics-do-spike-prime-and-mindstorms-robot-inventor-use).

Comment: There's some spec sheets at https://education.lego.com/en-us/product-resources/spike-prime/downloads/technical-specifications - does that suffice?

Comment: any chance to get the value or part no. of the hall sensor?

Comment: @AbdElhaleem In the answer the last sentence is this: "The part number on mine is BCZK 116." Does this answer your question? If not, please ask a dedicated question with the necessary details.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what the part looks like from the outside:

[image: exterior]

The first step to opening it up is to remove the cover over a section of the drive. Note that this process is likely to cause permanent damage to the part as it requires prying and bending.

[image: cover off]

We can now slide the gray back cover off.

[image: both covers off]

The PCB is clipped in at the front, but with some care we can separate the gearbox from the motor.

[image: gearbox separated]

The gearbox houses a pair of bevel gears. The gray one that is part of the drive shaft is 11 tooth and the smaller one is 9 tooth.

[image: gearbox]

With significant force, the drive shaft can be separated to remove it and reveal the magnet that is used to sense drive angle.

[image: drive shaft and magnet]

Moving back towards the motor, we find a double planetary gearbox similar to the one found in several motors without angular drives.

[image: double planetary]

[image: planetary side view]

The motor itself is soldered to a PCB. There's nothing other than traces on the side facing the motor, so I haven't bothered to desolder it.

[image: motor and PCB]

The main microcontroller appears to be an STM8S103. My part has the following part information:

```
S103
PHVG
939Y
```

The other significant visible part labeled `509R` is a thermistor that serves to put a hard limit on motor current.

Viewed from the other side, we can see the hall effect sensor that is used to detect drive angle. The part number on mine is `BCZK 116`.

[image: PCB top]