# What electronics are inside the SPIKE 3x3 LED Matrix?

Tags: electronics, disassembly, spike-prime

What is inside the LEGO 3x3 Color Light Matrix 45608?

[image]

Pictures of the assembled Top- & Bottom- PCB would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 clips holding this together. It isn't too difficult to get apart with a little prying. Here's what it looks like with the cover removed:

[image: Opened]

The board can then be popped out of the housing. Here's a close-up of the front:

[image: Front of board]

There are 9 surface-mount LEDs just as one might expect.

Here's a shot of the back of the board:

[image: Back of board]

The larger chip appears to be numbered:

```
V0269
3235A
```

I believe that this part is a [28-port dimmable LED driver](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/lumissil-microsystems/IS31FL3235A-QFLS2-TR/7219609). This provides enough output to drive the display (3 x 3 x 3 colors = 27 LEDs).

The smaller chip appears to be numbered:

```
S103
PHVC
0317
```

Here's a better shot of that chip:

[image: S103 Photo]

This looks like an STM8S103 microcontroller similar to the chip used in Powered Up [motors](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/16898/708) that provide position feedback.

There are also a number of smaller chips and passive components on the board, but they are probably a bit less interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much !
This Micro seems to be a Standard uC used for this Motor-/Sensor- Interfaces