What electronics are inside the Spike Essential parts?
The Spike Essential set introduces two new robotics parts; a two-port Spike hub (part 67351c01) and a 3x3 LED matrix (part 47592c01):


What electronics do they have inside? How do they compare to the electronics inside the larger Spike Prime hub?

the matrix is fully disassembled here: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18176
