# What is the gyro sampling rate on the Spike Prime hub?

Tags: programming, spike-prime, gyro

I was wondering what is the inertial measurement unit sampling rate, because for my project I need 800 Hertz. I tried to look in the firmware file but I didn’t find anything. I use the `pybricks` firmware on a Lego Spike Prime hub.

Answer (score 4):

Digging a bit into the C source code for the `pybricks` firmware, I was able to find [these two lines](https://github.com/pybricks/pybricks-micropython/blob/415910bd5f53cb538f4b58c8a23d2030096c86b6/lib/pbio/drv/imu/imu_lsm6ds3tr_c_stm32.c#L188):

```
PT_SPAWN(pt, &child, lsm6ds3tr_c_xl_data_rate_set(&child, ctx, LSM6DS3TR_C_XL_ODR_833Hz));
PT_SPAWN(pt, &child, lsm6ds3tr_c_gy_data_rate_set(&child, ctx, LSM6DS3TR_C_GY_ODR_833Hz));
```

...which means that the IMU is set to a sampling rate of 833Hz.

Please note that this is how the IMU electronics are configured when `pybricks` starts - this *does not necessarily mean* that the `pybricks` firmware nor the hub's microcontroller CPU can keep up with that rate, or that they can run some of your python code 833 times per second, or that `pybricks` will run python code at that rate.

It should be possible to change the sampling rate by modifying the `pybricks` C code and recompiling the firmware. If you want/need to take on this endeavour, read https://github.com/pybricks/pybricks-micropython#development first.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments of one of the accepted answer on the question here:
[What internal electronics do Spike Prime and Mindstorms Robot Inventor use?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/15057/what-internal-electronics-do-spike-prime-and-mindstorms-robot-inventor-use)
it's mentioned that the pybricks people have determined that the IMU module is a STMicroelectronics LSM6DS3TR-C.

Googling for this I found the following document on the manufacturers website: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6ds3tr-c.pdf
Which list output data rates from 1.6 Hz to 6.6kHz, probably depending on which mode the chip is configured in... I have no way off knowing which mode/value applies, but perhaps someone else does...